# What colors and/or designs exist for the CECHA consoles? (aka Fat with full PS2 Backwards Compatibility and Wi-Fi)

Tags: ps3

The CECHA PS3 consoles are very special due to being the only models with both full PS2 Backwards Compatibility via Hardware and Wi-Fi.

What colors and/or designs exist for the CECHA consoles?

Comment: Not going to answer because I don't know for certain, but I'm pretty sure it only came in the standard glossy black. The original PS3 version was only available for a very short time and on release I remember it being only available in black. The models without PS2 support replaced it pretty quickly and probably before any other designs of the old console could have come out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing some time browsing Yahoo Auctions Japan, eBay and other sites, I didn't found any CECHAXX console with a design other than Piano Black with the Chrome Trim.

I also confirmed this by checking the list of Colors and Designs in the unofficial [PS3 Developer Wiki](https://www.psdevwiki.com/ps3/Colours).